# sequel trying to use postgresql instead of postgres as adapters

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sequel

Had a simple heroku app with sequel and postgres. However, I got:

```
% heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/postgresql
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.23.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `require'
```

There is no postgresql.rb in the sequel-3.23.0/lib/sequel/adapters/ There is a postgres.rb on my local drive. I'm using the free plan.

```
% heroku info
...
Dynos:          1
Workers:        0
Repo size:      9M
Slug size:      8M
Stack:          bamboo-mri-1.9.2
Data size:      (empty)
Addons:         Basic Logging, Shared Database 5MB


% heroku pg:info
=== kampanchi database SHARED_DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: Is there a question in here?  If you use the "wrong" name for postgresql, does it work?

Answer (score 4):

Sequel has always used "postgres" for the postgres adapter.  If you have specified "postgresql" as the adapter scheme, then it shouldn't work.  If you are using Rails, Heroku creates a database.yml file in ActiveRecord format (using "postgresql"), and I'm guessing that's what your rake task is picking up.  If you are using a Rails/Sequel integration tool, I'm guessing it isn't handling that conversion for you, and it should be fixed.  Personally, I'd manually set up the database connection using the DATABASE_URL environment variable that Heroku provides.

See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#database_urls for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement Jeremy's response, Heroku has always used "postgres" in the `DATABASE_URL`. If you connect to `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]`, it should work regardless of what your database is.